# Простой код с массивом в обобщённом классе и непонятное ClassCastException

Tags: java, исключения, generics

```
class Super {}

class Sub extends Super {}

class GenericArrayHolder<T extends Super>
{
    T[] array;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    GenericArrayHolder(int n)
    {
        array = (T[]) new Super[n];
    }

    void set(int i, T t)
    {
        array[i] = t;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        GenericArrayHolder<Sub> h = new GenericArrayHolder<>(10);
        h.set(3, new Sub());
        h.array[3] = new Sub(); // ClassCastException
    }
}
```

Собственно вопрос в том, почему 3 строчка в main генерирует исключение? Особенно меня удивляет, что это происходит не смотря на то, что 2 строчка работает нормально.

Comment: А хороший вопрос, почему никто не плюсует? Думаю, очередная проблема из-за type erasure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кажется, я понял. Дело таки в type erasure.

Смотрите, вот эксперимент. Уберём `new Sub()`, запишем просто `null`. http://ideone.com/zXc7kG

Получим ошибку: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [LSuper; cannot be cast to [LSub;`.

Документация говорит, что `[LSuper;` означает **массив** элементов типа `Super`, a `[LSub;` — массив элементов типа `Sub`.

Как работает type erasure? На время компиляции `T` заменяется на `Super`, и всё, что выдаёт наружу `T`, обкладывается рантайм-проверками. То есть код `h.array` на самом деле превращается в `(Sub[])h.array`.

В вашем случае `array` на самом деле типа `Super[]`, каст из-за type erasure не обнаруживает, что тип-то не тот! Ошибка возникает лишь при доступе.

Что делать? Создайте несущий массив правильного типа:

```
array = (Т[])Array.newInstance(cl, 10);
```

Для этого вам понадобится класс:

```
GenericArrayHolder(int n, Class<T> cl)
{
    array = (Т[])Array.newInstance(cl, 10);
}
```

Более прямого пути с type erasure, кажется, нет.

Comment: Более прямой пусть — использовать языки с нормальными дженериками. ;)

Comment: С C# такой проблемы не возникает, да.

Comment: Только в (Sub[])h.array, если я правильно понял)

Comment: @zer_ik: Точно! Сейчас исправлю.

Answer (score 2):

Это привет от type erasure.

В коде дженериков на самом деле хранится код для базового типа, и везде расставляются преобразования типов. В вашем случае код:

```
array = (T[]) new Super[n];
```

на самом деле выполняется так:

```
array = (Super[]) new Super[n];
```

потому что `T` в `GenericArrayHolder` ограничен "снизу" этим типом.

Когда вы выполняете метод у дженерикового типа, то все касты корректно расставляются, в результате код:

```
array[i] = t;
```

выполняется так:

```
array[i] = (Super)t;
```

Когда же вы обращаетесь к массиву напрямую, то компилятор считает, что массив надо преобразовать к типу `Sub[]`. Сделать он этого не может, отсюда исключение.

Похожий вопрос был рассмотрен на английском Stack Overflow: [Generic array throws ClassCastException when referenced directly (it doesn't when calling through helper method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746693/generic-array-throws-classcastexception-when-referenced-directly-it-doesnt-whe). Там в похожем коде исключение выбрасывается даже при обращении к полю массива `length`.

Comment: Успели раньше :-) Я как раз пишу.

Comment: @VladD Если так будет продолжаться, я скоро джаву изучу... %)

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вам массив типа T?
Можно хранить массив Super, и тогда все отлично работает.

```
class Super {}

class Sub extends Super {}

class GenericArrayHolder<T extends Super>
{
    Super[] array;

    GenericArrayHolder(int n)
    {
        array = new Super[n];
    }

    void set(int i, T t)
    {
        array[i] = t;
    }
}

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GenericArrayHolder<Sub> h = new GenericArrayHolder<>(10);
        h.set(3, new Sub());
        h.array[3] = null;
    }
}
```